# Matlab - Not getting the expected result

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have written a function that is supposed to do the following:

- Take as an input two sets
- Take the distance between the two sets using `pdist2` which code is shown [here](http://code.google.com/p/cs250b-projects/source/browse/trunk/Project3/toolbox/classify/pdist2.m?spec=svn81&r=81).
- It will take the distance between the two sets at the beginning. Then, for the **second** set, at each iteration, it will set the (i,j) location to `0` and calculate the distance with this change. An, when it goes to the next iteration, it should change the next location value to '0' while at the same time return the preceding value which was set to '0' to its *original value*.
- Note that the result from `pdist2` originally return as a matrix, but for the comparison, I sum up the matrix values to use them for comparison.

Based on that, I have written the following function (note that you can use the `pdist2.m` function from the link [here](http://code.google.com/p/cs250b-projects/source/browse/trunk/Project3/toolbox/classify/pdist2.m?spec=svn81&r=81)):

```
   function m = pixel_minimize_distance(x,y)
    sum1=0;
    sum2=0;
    [r c] = size(y);
    d1 = pdist2(x,y);
    [r1 c1] = size(d1);
    for i=1:r1
    for j=1:c1
        sum1=sum1+d1(i,j);
    end
end
maximum = sum1;

for i=1:r
for j=1:c
o = y(i,j)
y(i,j) = 0;
d2 = pdist2(x,y);
[r2 c2] = size(d2);
for i=1:r2
    for j=1:c2
        sum2=sum2+d2(i,j);
    end
end

if sum2 >= maximum
    if o ~= 0
    maximum = sum2;
    m = o;
    end

end

if sum2 <= maximum
maximum = maximum;
end
y(i,j)=o;
end
end
end
```

Now, this is what I have run as a test:

```
>> A=[1 2 3; 6 5 4];
>> B=[4 5 3; 7 8 1];
>> pixel_minimize_distance(A,B)

o =

     4


o =

     4


o =

     1


o =

     7


o =

     7


o =

     0


ans =

     7
```

See the the answer here is `7` (scroll down if you cannot see it), while the expected value when I calculate this manually should be `3`, as since when we set it to `0` the sum of the distance will be `142`.

Any idea what could be wrong in the code? I think it would be in the location in the code of setting `o = y(i,j)` where `o` denotes *original value*, but really couldn't figure a way of solving that.

Thanks.

Comment: You have an `end` which has no corresponding `for`

Comment: @ogzd. I think you mean the last `end` which is for the function. It seems in my post the first few lines didn't show up, but have modified my code now. Thanks

Comment: Could you place the comments in the code with a `%` as it is not really clear which part is supposed to do what.Also try stepping through the code untill you see something strange with f10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have many redundant commands in your code. I just removed them, nothing else. I am getting value of `m` as `3`. I used MATLAB's `pdist2` function with squared euclidean distance (since that is the default in the function you provided). I did not get 142 as the distance.

Here is the code:

```
function m = pixel_minimize_distance(x,y)
[r c] = size(y);
maximum = (sum(sum(pdist2(x,y)))).^2; %explained below

for i=1:r
    for j=1:c
        o = y(i,j);
        y(i,j) = 0
        sum2 = (sum(sum(pdist2(x,y)))).^2;


        if sum2 >= maximum
            if o ~= 0
                maximum = sum2;
                m = o;
            end
        end

        y(i,j)=o;
    end
end
end
```

and output is:

y =

```
 0     5     3
 7     8     1
```

y =

```
 4     0     3
 7     8     1
```

y =

```
 4     5     0
 7     8     1
```

y =

```
 4     5     3
 0     8     1
```

y =

```
 4     5     3
 7     0     1
```

y =

```
 4     5     3
 7     8     0
```

m =

```
 3
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Explanation:
You have written the following snippet of code:

```
d2 = pdist2(x,y);
[r2 c2] = size(d2);
for i=1:r2
    for j=1:c2
        sum2=sum2+d2(i,j);
    end
end
```

what this simply does is calculates the distance between two sets using `pdist2` and sums up the entire distance matrix to come up with one value stored in `sum2` in your case. 
Lets look at the my code:

```
sum2 = (sum(sum(pdist2(x,y)))).^2;
```

`pdist2` will give the distance. First `sum` command will sum along the rows and then the second one will sum along the columns to give you a total of all values in the matrix (This is what you did with two `for` loops). Now, the reason behind `.^2` is: 
In the original `pdist2` function in the link which you have provided, you can see from the following snippet of code:

```
if( nargin<3 || isempty(metric) ); metric=0; end;

switch metric
  case {0,'sqeuclidean'}
```

that squared Euclidean is the default distance, whereas in MATLAB, Euclidean distance is default. Therefore, I have squared the term.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Comment: Nice, the code could indeed use some cleanup! Though you obviously did change something as the original code will give 7, even with the default setting. I guess the original contained a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @Parag. Thanks for your reply. Can you just explain to me what ` (sum(sum(pdist2(x,y)))).^2;` means? What is `.^2`'s purpose?

Comment: Rather than comparing the sum to the maximum he compares the squares, probably not required here but in general this ensures that you don't get surprised by negative values.